# How to GZIP files on Java and send it through the OutputStream

Tags: java, sockets, server, gzip

I am using the **GZIPOutputStream** class to GZIP an image. I receive a corrupted file when I try to send the GZIP file through the OutputStream.  I know how to GZIP to a FileOutputStream.  The following code works perfectly:

```
Static private void GZIPCompress(String fileName)
{
        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        fis.read(data); 
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName + ".gz");
        GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(fos); 
        gzos.write(data);
        fos.close();
        fis.close();
 }
```

The output file is myfile.png.gz and has the following **details**:

> myfile.png.gz: gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2,
>   NT)

My problem is when I try to GZIP a file and send it to the **OutputStream**. Since I'm working with a server, I am calling this from my server and I am using sockets.

```
Static void SendGZIPFile(String fileName, OutputStream os)
{
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        byte[] dataAux = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        dos.writeBytes("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/x-gzip \r\n");
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="+"\""+fileName+".gz"+"\""+"\n");
        dos.writeBytes("\r\n\r\n");
        dos = new DataOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(os));
        fis.read(data);
        dos.write(data);
        dos.close();
        fis.close();
        gzos.close();
}
```

What I get is a corrupted GZIP file that contains nothing: here are the **details**:

> myfile.gz data

I think I'm doing something wrong while GZipping because I noticed the differences between the **details**.  I use the following command to get it: `file myfile.gz`

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you manually doing HTTP instead of using a library/framework?

Comment: PNG is already compressed so attempting to GZIP it as well is likely to make it larger.

Comment: Can you please also show the part that calls `SendGZIPFile(fileName, outputStream)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flush `gzos` before closing `dos`. Or close `gzos` first.

Comment: please notice that my problem is with the second function sendGZIPFiles and i dont have a variable gzos.

Comment: sorry, `gzos.close();` confused me

Comment: Your line terminators seem fishy, try removing the \n in the content-disposition line.

Comment: Thank you it's because of the \n, i deleted it and now its compressing!!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from your code lacking fundamental correctness (you should probably not be implementing HTTP in your code, smarter people have already done so in the past), I think the problem is that you are not correctly copying data. Instead, you should be doing copying in a loop like this:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while((len = fis.read(buf)) != -1)
{
    dos.write(buf, 0, len);
}
```

Or you could just use Apache Commons IO:

```
IOUtils.copy(fis, dos);
```